# Table in Two Column

Tags: tables, two-column

I am trying to generate a table in a two column document. However, the table also appears in the column settings. I want that table should appear in the one column settings in the float environment. The minimum working example is given below:

```
      \documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage{times}
      \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[english]{babel}
      \usepackage[final]{graphicx}
      \usepackage{natbib}
      \setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }
      \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
      \captionsetup[table]{skip = 3pt}
      \usepackage{tabulary}
      \usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
      \usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
      \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
      \usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
      \usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
      \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
      \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
      \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

      \begin{document}
      \section{INTRODUCTION}
      This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. 

      \begin{table}[!htb]
          \centering
          \footnotesize
          \caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies} \label{tab:freq}
          \caption*{
              \footnotesize
              This table provides the frequencies 
          } 

          \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{ccccr}
              \toprule
              Year  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nones} & Option  1 & Option 2 & Total \\
              \midrule
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2001} & 126   & 16    & 2     & 144 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2002} & 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2003} & 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2004} & 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2005} & 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2006} & 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2007} & 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2008} & 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2009} & 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2010} & 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
              \multicolumn{1}{r}{2011} & 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
              \midrule      
              Total & 1,097 & 52    & 61    & 1,210 \\
              \bottomrule
          \end{tabulary}
      \end{table}
       This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.
      \end{document}
```

Comment: You want your table to be full text width?

Comment: your table perfectly fit in one column. what is the problem? beside unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{r}{...}` ... i can't find anything wrong.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements, but it looks to me like you want a table that occupies the width of a full column. If this is the case, you should look into using a `tabular*` environment with a width set to `\columnwidth`. Oh, and don't use both a `\caption` and a `\caption*` directive for one and the same `figure` -- it's abuse of notation, if not something worse.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,margin=3cm}
\usepackage{caption}% <-- added
\captionsetup[table]{skip = 3pt}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
\usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
\usepackage{caption}% <-- added
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section.

Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. 

\begin{table}[!htb]
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
\caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies} \label{tab:freq}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX compute intercolumn whitespace
\footnotesize\centering
This table provides the frequencies.

\smallskip 
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rcccr}
\toprule
  Year  & Nones& Option  1 & Option 2 & Total \\
\midrule
  2001& 126   & 16    & 2     & 144 \\
  2002& 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
  2003& 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
  2004& 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
  2005& 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
  2006& 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
  2007& 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
  2008& 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
  2009& 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
  2010& 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
  2011& 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
  \midrule
  Total & 1,097 & 52    & 61    & 1,210 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. 

Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.
Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. 

Here is a the text about the introduction.Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's followup comment: To make the tabular material span *both* columns, all you need to change in the code shown above answer is (a) replace both of instances of `{table}` with `{table*}` and replace `\columnwidth` with `\textwidth`. Do be aware, though, that LaTeX places table* and figure* environments only at the *top* of a page. Since there's more than enough space now, you should probably get rid of the `footnotesize` directives, though.

[image]

---

*Second Addendum*: Further analysis of the contents of the `table` environments shows that (a) it's not necessary to switch to `\footnotesize` and (b) it would useful, from the point of making the numeric information more readable, to align the numbers in the four data columns on their (implicit) decimal markers. This may be achieved by loading the `siunitx` package and employing the `S` column type.

Separately, since you're using the `IEEEtran` document class, I would *not* load the `caption` package, as doing so modifies the appearance of captions rather decisively. I would assume that you're using `IEEEtran` for a solid reason; you should thus be rather careful to change the layout and appearance of table and figure captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[verbose,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,group-separator={,}}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

% macro for a paragraph of filler text
\newcommand\blurb{This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is the text about the introduction.\par}

%\flushbottom % may not be necessary

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\blurb\blurb
\begin{table}[!htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies} \label{tab:freq}
\centering
This table provides the frequencies.

\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
    l T{4}T{2}T{2}T{4}}
\toprule
Year & {Nones}& {Option 1} & {Option 2} & {Total} \\
\midrule
  2001& 126   & 16    & 2     & 144 \\
  2002& 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
  2003& 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
  2004& 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
  2005& 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
  2006& 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
  2007& 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
  2008& 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
  2009& 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
  2010& 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
  2011& 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
  \midrule
  Total & 1097 & 52   & 61    & 1210 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\blurb\blurb\blurb\blurb
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to spread the table over two columns instead of being shown in one column.

Comment: but for this is no reason! natural width of your table is smaller than width of one column. If you persist to have so wide table, than `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}` will give what you like to have, of course, on the top of the next page.

Comment: @AhmedArif - I've provided an addendum to address your follow-up comment. The only changes to the code I posted initially is to switch from a `table` to a `table*` environment and to use `\textwidth` instead of `\columnwidth` in the first argument of `tabular*`.

Comment: @Mico, How to make the last table small on page?

Comment: @AadityaUra - I'm afraid I don't understand your question. The table was designed in a single column, and it does just that. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Mico in simple words, I have data with 6 columns in each table. What is the best way to display them? when those two tables are having same column but repeated for different models. for example those six columns are `Accuracy, f1-score, Precision, Recall, domain accuracy, overall` this is content of one table, Now I have to show this same table for two model's result.

Comment: @Mico So two tables side by side would be better to show both model result. Your suggestion how to show them is welcome.

Comment: Please post a *new query*, and please be sure to mention all relevant document-related constraints. E.g., which document class do you employ, which fonts and which font size do you employ?

Answer (score 10):

If you persist to span your table over two columns, despite its natural width is smaller than one column width, than you should use

```
\begin{table*}
...
\end{table*}
```

(regarding this, your question is duplicate to many question here...). This tables can appear only on top of the (next) page. To force it to be in bottom of current page, you need to load package `stfloats`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }
\usepackage{caption}% <-- added
\captionsetup[table]{skip = 3pt}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,tabularx,tabulary}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}%
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table*}[b]
    \centering
%        \footnotesize
\caption{Year Wise Treatment Frequencies}
    \label{tab:freq}
\caption*{\footnotesize
      This table provides the frequencies
            }
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{S @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            *{4}{S[group-separator = {,},
                                   group-minimum-digits = 4
                                    ]}}
      \toprule
  {Year} & {Nones} & {Option 1} & {Option 2} & {Total}  \\
      \midrule
  2001       & 126   & 16    & 2     & 144 \\
  2002       & 114   & 9     & 4     & 127 \\
  2003       & 115   & 7     & 1     & 123 \\
  2004       & 114   & 6     & 4     & 124 \\
  2005       & 104   & 5     & 8     & 117 \\
  2006       & 96    & 3     & 6     & 105 \\
  2007       & 93    & 2     & 4     & 99 \\
  2008       & 93    & 2     & 2     & 97 \\
  2009       & 85    & 2     & 11    & 98 \\
  2010       & 83    & 0     & 7     & 90 \\
  2011       & 74    & 0     & 12    & 86 \\
      \midrule
      Total & 1097 & 52    & 61    & 1210 \\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

In above table for column formatting the `siunitx` column type `S` is used. To my opinion the result is very, very ugly ...  Well, maybe your real table need to be so wide, who knows :)